# grafana query to count same values until value changes

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable

Good afternoon.   So I am creating a grafana dashboard and I am having a problem with counting a unique number in a list until the number changes.  I am counting the number of times a service is unavailable,  when the ping rate is 100% loss.  The check happens 48 times in one day.  So I have a query that shows the timestamp and the ping loss number.  What I want to do is to count the number of 100's until the result is any other number. I want the result to be from now back to the first non-100. I am using influx as the data source.

```
Example data

Date              result
1/1/2023 02:01     100
1/1/2023 01:31     100
1/1/2023 01:01     100
1/1/2023 12:31      88
1/1/2023 12:01      24
```

In the above data set the result would be 3. The counting would stop at the 88.  Like I said I have the query setup already to pull the data into grafana now I just need a hand on the rest.  Thank you for your help.

I have been at it for a while, I have tried a bunch of different things from this site and others. Really open to any suggestions.

Comment: Such a task is usually better solved on the dbms' side. I'm not familiar with influx to say anything more useful, but I suggest you digging into that direction.

Comment: Thank you for the quick post. Unfortunately, I can only manipulate the data results. No backend access for me.

Comment: What do you mean? If you can apply transformation to panel, than you also can change query to database. I suggested you to write a correct query, that will return data that you want.

Comment: Outstanding suggestion thank you.